# Text on top of button image line-up cross-crowser?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've setup a quick jsfiddle with the issue at hand.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gdnbe/

If you widen the result pane you'll notice everything is sitting inline.

When I take a look at it in firefox, everything seems to be lining up properly (button image height is longer than inputs but should sit vertically centered), including the text "Log in".

In chrome, however, it moves the button text to the bottom of the button and the button isn't sitting nicely inline with the inputs, it is too high.

The code in question:

```
<input name="submit" value="Log in" style="background: url(' http://www..../images/btn-bg.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: none;
    /*border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;*/
    color: #999999;
    padding: 0.7em 0.8em 1.1em;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 146px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;" type="submit">
```

What's the next step in making this cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the padding on the button.  Remove it and the problem goes away.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gdnbe/1/

```
Just look at the fiddle (stupid "Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" rule)
```

This is the best you can do if you want to stick to using background images.  If you want to have all of your elements line up perfectly, consider using a few goodies from CSS3:

- border-radius
- linear-gradient
- box-shadow

Comment: Yeah, its a limitation you'll have to live with if you're using images.  You can't control how the browser is going to render text.  That entire form could be entirely recreated with the CSS3 goodies I listed.